# How do I bind to a combobox display value?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

How do I bind to a combobox's *name* (ie display text) to some other component?

I have a combobox called 'combo', and I have a label in a panel somewhere else that updates itself with the combo display value. The two widgets are bound via a ViewModel.

If I set the bindings like this :

```
combo.setConfig({bind: {value: bindName}};
```

then the label will show the *value* of the combo (ie. key).

If I do this :

```
combo.setConfig({bind: {name: bindName}};
```

then I get this error message :

> "Cannot bind name on Ext.form.field.ComboBox - missing a setName
>   method."

I have gone through other getter/setter methods in combobox with no success, having tried :

> combo.setConfig({bind: {name: displayField}};
>
> combo.setConfig({bind: {name: rawValue}};

Fiddle : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1bum

Comment: The `name` of a combobox is not the display text, but the name of the form field (if the name is `combo1`, the form will submit the value `value` as `combo1:value` or store it in the model field with name `combo1`. You are trying to bind to the "display value", which has no property and no config option to set it. I fear that you would have to do the bind manually. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: basically i want to bind a combo with display/value pairs. I want to show the display text on a panel somewhere else in my application.

Comment: here is a fiddle that demonstrates the problem : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1bum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a reference to the combo and bind to the selection:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.TestView', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    layout: 'form',

    viewModel: {
        type: 'test' // references alias "viewmodel.test"
    },

    bind: {
        title: 'Hello {name} {theCombo.selection.name}'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'first name',
        bind: '{name}'

    }, {
        valueField: 'id',
        displayField: 'name',
        fieldLabel: 'last name',
        reference: 'theCombo',
        xtype: 'combo',
        bind: '{combo}',
        store: {
            fields: ['id', 'name'],
            data: [{
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Jonston"
            }, {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Billson"
            }, {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "Wayneston"
            }]
        }
    }]
});
```